# Make and Install curl latest version on RedHat 5

Tags: curl, libcurl

I have development Linux server using Red Hat 5 with Curl version# 7.15.5.
For the given Linux version that's the last curl version provided by Red Hat.

I have to use Git to checkout the code but when trying to do git checkout it does not support < TLSV2.0 as lower protocols are depricated.

I have last option to update the curl version to latest, I have tried installing the curl from source but seems its not getting install properly.

I have few questions. 
- If I install latest curl from source will it affect current curl installed.
- Is it possible to only use latest curl for Git code checkout and leave out of the box curl as it is. 
- There is no connectivity with internet so only looking to install from source.

Thanks
Vivek Singh

GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git ls-remote https://bitbucket.org/
* Couldn't find host bitbucket.org in the .netrc file, using defaults
* About to connect() to proxy 10.200.80.200 port 8080
*   Trying 10.200.80.200... * connected
* Connected to 10.200.80.200 (10.200.80.200) port 8080
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to bitbucket.org:443

> CONNECT bitbucket.org:443 HTTP/1.0
>   Host: bitbucket.org:443
>   User-Agent: git/2.9.5
>   Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>   Accept-Language: en-US, *;q=0.9
>   Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
<
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection #0
fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/': error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Current Curl version.

curl 7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap http file https ftps
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz